# Removing Element from XML by python if contains specific subelement

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to remove whole element when it contains certain subelement. I Figured out how to and my code works fine on small sample files, but when i try it over big vile (over 20Mb) it removes just some elements. If I run the code repeatedly over results, for some reason it after several runs removes all the elements I expected in first run, which is just random luck I guess, that the code does not give exception or some error in a first place.

XML sample:

```
<root>
<element1>
  <sub1>
    <subsub1>
    </subsub1>
  </sub1>
  <sub2>
    <subsub2>
       <foo STyp="foo">
         <bar>
         </bar>
       </foo>
    </subsub2>
  </sub2>
</element1>
</root>
```

I want to delete the whole element1 if it contains `<foo STyp="foo"></foo>`.

code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("my.xml")

for root in tree.iter():
    for element1 in root:
            el = element1.find('foo')
            if el is not None:
                root.remove(element1)

tree.write('1.xml')
```

I'm just puzzled it works on smaller file

Answer (score 0):

from [`Element.iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) documentation:

> If the tree structure is modified during iteration, the result is undefined.

your problem is you are modifying the tree while iterating its elements.
you can use [*XPath*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) to find grandparents of your desiered elements. then find their parents in it and remove the parent element from grandparent element. (because python xml doesn't allow you to access parents directly.)

```py
for grandparent_of_foo in root.findall(".//foo[@STyp='foo']/../../."):
  for parent_of_foo in grandparent_of_foo.findall("*/foo[@STyp='foo']/../."):
    grandparent_of_foo.remove(parent_of_foo)
```

for this input:

```xml
<root>
<element1>
  <sub1>
    <subsub1>
      <subsub4>
        <foo STyp="foo">
        </foo>
      </subsub4>
    </subsub1>
  </sub1>
  <sub2>
    <subsub2>
       <foo STyp="foo">
         <bar>
         </bar>
       </foo>
    </subsub2>
    <subsub3>
      <bar>
      </bar>
    </subsub3>
  </sub2>
</element1>
</root>
```

printing the `root` node would produce this result:

```py
print(ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8').decode())
```

```xml
<root>
<element1>
  <sub1>
    <subsub1>
      </subsub1>
  </sub1>
  <sub2>
    <subsub3>
      <bar>
      </bar>
    </subsub3>
  </sub2>
</element1>
</root>
```

you can check out *Xpath* syntax [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support).